# Why are the constructors of a member variable of a class run first?

Tags: c++

I could not find any information about this. Apparently if I have a class that contains objects of another class, the constructor for those member objects are run first. For example:

```
class A {
   int b;
   Foo x;
   Foo y;
public:
   A(int newInt) : b(newInt) {}
}
```

If I create an instance of A by using A(4), then apparently the constructors for x and y run first.

Why is that? Doesn't the constructor for A need to be run first to create the member variables in the first place?

Comment: The reason for initialising the fields first should be clear, i.e. you want your object of type `A` to be inialize to a defined state and not having to deal with garbage. In general, whenever you declare a variable of a certain class in C++ like you're doing, it always constructs a new object by calling the default constructor.

Comment: @nbro that intuition makes sense to me, thanks

Comment: In the constructor of `A` you might want to call a method of `x` or `y`. They need to be already initialized (constructed) in order to work with them, isn't it? That's why the constructors of the member properties are executed first, before the code of class `A` constructor.